# MYSQL bug when try to select X number of rows and this X number doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I have a large database with at least 50M rows.  If I try

```
select * 
  from mydatabase 
 where userid = '123456' 
 order 
    by id desc 
 limit 1000
```

...but the number of rows for this `userid` is only 700 mysql takes long time. 100x more than if I use

> select * from mydatabase where userid='123456' order by id desc limit 700

I don't know what is happening and I don't know if there is some way to fix it.  I just know that I can't count first because it takes long time, at least 90s.  I can't order by `id` without `limit` because it takes long time, at least 130s.

I just don't know what to do, and found nothing on google.

Comment: is 'id' indexed?

Comment: sounds like you need to review the indexes on your table

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I cleaned up your question a bit, but it's still a little hard to understand what your question is and what you have tried.

Comment: Yes. See indexes. Drop the inverted commas. And name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: "Why is my query slow?" questions are impossible to answer without a query plan. Produce the plans for a fast query and a slow query and add them to your question

Comment: rrauenza thanks for your help. Caius Jard, my problem is now why my query is slow, because if I select with limit 1 for example, takes 0.004s to display, but if I set without limit it takes a long time and if I set any value that doesn't exist, same problem occur. I wanna know why this is happening and if there is something to do to fix this